# Calculate the sum $x+y+z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If positive real numbers $x,y,z$ satisfying the conditions
$$x^2+xy+y^2=25, y^2+yz+z^2=49, z^2+zx+x^2=64$$ 
then calculate the sum $x+y+z.$

My attempt:

By subtracting equalities are obtained $$(z-x)(x+y+z)=24, (x-y)(x+y+z)=15.$$

And here I stopped.    )-:

Comment: Hint : deduce $24(x-y)=15(z-x)$. Can you finish from here ?

Comment: I knew $3x=8y+5z$, but we did not accept continuing through a cumbersome algebraic calculation.  I think it's more elegant geometric path response time joined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Geometric background]

$\angle ADB=\angle CDB= \angle ADC=120^{\circ}$

$D -$ Torricelli Point

$$S_{ADB}+S_{CDB}+S_{ADC}=S_{ABC}$$
$$\frac 12 xy \sin 120^{\circ}+\frac 12 zy \sin 120^{\circ}+\frac 12 xz \sin 120^{\circ}=\sqrt{10 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}$$
$$\frac {\sqrt 3}{4} xy +\frac {\sqrt 3}{4} zy +\frac {\sqrt 3}{4} xz=6\sqrt{5}$$
$$\frac {\sqrt 3}{4}(xy+yz+zx)=6\sqrt{5}$$
$$xy+yz+zx=\frac{24\sqrt 5}{\sqrt3}$$
$$x^2+xy+y^2+y^2+yz+z^2+z^2+zx+x^2=25+64+49$$ 
$$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+4xy+4yz+4zx=138+3 \cdot \frac{24\sqrt 5}{\sqrt3}$$
$$(x+y+z)^2=69+12\sqrt{15}$$
$$$$

Comment: Nice visualization, but how do you proceed from here ?

Comment: $x+y+z$ - minimum $PA+PB+PC$ for any interior point $P$ of the triangle

Comment: I see : when you have $xy+yz+zx$, you have also access to $(x+y+z)^2$. But that's way more complicated than the purely algebraic solution in my comment to the OP

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy: Yes, you are right

Comment: On the other hand, it would be ungraceful to leave your effort unrewarded. +1

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy:Thank you

Comment: @Roman83: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the above geometrical solution, but I have noticed the importance of using area in calculating the number $ xy + yz + zx. $